# Ajax request in Rails3, can't get it to work

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ujs

I try to refactor my project using AJAX.
I have a Link ...

```
= link_to("Please work", "show_recent_chart", :remote => true)
```

... a xxx-controller action ...

```
def show_recent_chart
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

... and a show_recent_chart.js.erb Template

```
alert("Done!");
```

My Logfile says after clicking the Link:

```
Started GET "/show_recent_chart" for 10.0.2.2 at 2012-04-30 05:56:43 -0400
Processing by XXXController#show_recent_chart as JS
MONGODB (0ms) 
  Rendered xxx/show_recent_chart.js.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
  Rendered shared/_header.slim (18.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.slim (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 8360ms (Views: 1276.0ms)
```

so it looks everything works fine. But the javascript code in the js.erb Template is never executed. Firebug just shows the request but nothing else.

How can I get this to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out.
Using firebug I saw that the response to my ajax request was the complete html document.
I had to use

```
format.js { render :layout => false }
```

to do the job.